# Get attribute from products listed on homepage

Tags: magento-1.7

On Magento we have products listed on the homepage and it is working fine. I would like to read this custom attribute added to the general section of products in the list file to do a check.

It is a yes/no attribute.

Tried doing the following as a test:

```
if($this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('iscomingsoon', array('like' => '1')) == 1)
{
    echo "huzzah!";
}
```

The attribute is `iscomingsoon`. It is always return true even if the option is set to no.

EDIT:
The following will work on the actual product view page:
    getProduct();
      echo $_product->getiscomingsoon();//displays 1 if yes
    ?>

^^ will not work on the homepage. Basically we have products that are coming soon. These products are supposed to not be clickable, have a rating, add to cart button, or quantity. The only thing it should have is an image of the product saying coming soon. When the products are no longer coming soon and are released then change Coming Soon option from Yes to No.

Basically my thinking is to have an if statement checking if product's coming soon option is yes (value=1). If yes then display product as described above with just coming soon image. The product collection is loaded on the homepage grid. Not sure what to do in order to get the attribute. Probably something simple I'm missing but I can't seem to get it...

Thanks for your time,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huzzah! Got it working.  I used the following to get the attribute value:

```
$_product->getData('iscomingsoon')
```